# Same response different method provides different Error output in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception

Say I have a errorResponse class, without getter and setter(intentionally) to understand the difference in Error Output.

```
class ErrorResponse {
    private String field;
    private String message;

    public ErrorResponse(String field, String message) {
        this.field = field;
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Now say we have a GetMapping

```
@GetMapping("/m1")
public ErrorResponse m1(HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("m1()....");
    return new ErrorResponse("abc", "jhfjd");
}
```

1. I understand we should get error code 500 with Spring default error output message,
   But getting 406 why???

```
    {
        "timestamp": "2023-11-08T00:41:58.682+00:00",
        "status": 406,
        "error": "Not Acceptable",
        "path": "/employee/m1"
    }
```

2. When I try to throw an error in m1 as below, and handles it under @ExceptionHandler, I get the Spring default error as expected with error code 500.

```
 @GetMapping("/m1")
    public ErrorResponse m1(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("m1()....");
        System.out.println(10/0);
        return new ErrorResponse("abc", "jhfjd");
    }
    
    @ExceptionHandler
    public ErrorResponse handleArithmeticException(ArithmeticException ex) {
        System.out.println("Ex-handleArithmeticException..........");
       return new ErrorResponse("abc", "1234");
    }
```

Error Output :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-11-08T00:49:44.577+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/employee/m1"
}
```

Note : Please correct me if I am wrong, I do understand that with code there is no issue, the error is with the Jackson part where it is unable to parse ErrorResponse to JSON.
But what I don't understand why two different output, expected error should be Spring default error message with error code 500.

Please help to understand the flow and internally working I am missing? Thanks

Comment: Have you try to add getter and setter  with ```ErrorResponse``` ?  ,the previous error is  occur in springframe work ,  the behind error is  happen to  serialization  ,there is no  getter and setter so the it could not  convert bean as return string . the difference  between may be there is some annotation which like ```@ResponseBody``` or some else ,type the value as string ? demonstrate more info  could helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, 406 is returned because an error occurred during serialization of ErrorResponse. The code is in line 322 of AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor,and subsequent execution ends normally.

The second case is that the exception thrown when the interface is executed is caught by the exception handler, and then an error occurs during serialization of the ErrorResponse returned by the exception handler. That is to say, an error occurred during the execution of the exception handler, but the exception was not thrown. It returns null directly. The code is in line 422 of ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver. Finally, the exception is converted into ServletException and the response is set to error in line 198 of StandardWrapperValve. Finally, tomcat's ErrorPage is executed.

The spring boot version I am using is 3.1.5